# Insert into table from stored proc

Tags: sql

I am trying to use a stored procedure that contains two different cursors as table input like such:

```
INSERT INTO table1 EXEC * FROM tblDailySales
```

The stored proc contains two cursors - I did not run just using.

I get the following error:

> A cursor with the name 'csrDistricts' does not exist.

I also, get this error

> An `INSERT EXEC` statement cannot be nested

The stored proc contains no `EXEC` that I can see.

What kind of stored proc other than simple `SELECT` can be used as source for table?

Comment: Why on earth are you using cursors to begin with? Cursors are not a recommended way to do any insert.

Answer (score 1):

Is table1 already defined?  If so all you should have to do is

```
INSERT INTO table1
EXEC storedProcedureName
```

Now, the trick is, the stored procedure will only be able to return **one** result set and insert into the table.

If you need to insert two different result sets, you'll have to gather then in two different stored procedures, then run two INSERT statements.

If you must do them at once, you'll need to do the insert from within the stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, Table1 is already define.  There is only one result set being returned.  The errors are indciating that the cursor can't be found.

Comment: Ohhh, Also, the there is a exec in the sp that may the real cause of the trouble.